# Recursive isMember method with only two arguments!

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, boolean

I need to create a recursive Boolean method named isMemeber. The method should accept two arguments ONLY: an array and a value. The method should return true if the value is found in the array, or false if the value is not found in the array.

I think that the base case will be if the passed array is empty, but I need help with the recursive case:

```
public static boolean isMember(int[] array, int value)
{
    if(array.length==0){
        return false; 
    }else{
        return isMember(???);           
    }
}
```

Here is how it looks with position variable:

```
public static boolean isMember(int[] array, int value, int position)
{
    if (position > -1)
    {

        if (array[position] == value)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return isMember(array, value, position - 1);
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Why does this need to be recursive?  If it's homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: Yes, it's a homework. Do you have any solutions?

Comment: I don't see the recursion aspect since the array parameter is a flat array; no depth or child members.

Comment: Surely a solution that involves making a copy of all or part of the array is not intended? (It's idiomatic in some languages, but not in Java.)

Comment: I know it's not effective to use recursion in this case, but this exercise is part of Recursion chapter in "Starting out with Java, Early Objects" by Tony Gaddis (page 938, ex 2).

Comment: As homework I suppose the question has at least that much merit.  However, I would argue that teaching a student to use recursion when it isn't needed and is the wrong tool for the job isn't really teaching the student anything of value.  _When_ to use recursion (or any tool) is just as important as _how_ to use recursion.  This assignment teaches the latter, but entirely fails to teach the former.  It does just as much harm as good.

Comment: Must be a translation from a LISP exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use recursion you can copy the array on each recursion.  This is inefficent, but using recursion is inefficient compared with using a loop. e.g. `Arrays.indexOf()`

```
public static boolean isMember(int[] array, int value) {
    if(array.length == 0) return false; 
    if(array[0] == value) return true;
    int[] array2 = new int[array.length-1];
    System.arraycopy(array,1,array2,0,array2.length);
    return isMember(array2, value);           
}
```

Comment: This is really smart solution, Sir. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Ironically, arraycopy would use a loop in its implementation. ;)

Comment: Wow...yep, that's recursive. Only problem is you gave the OP teh codez and we shouldn't do that for homework ;)

Comment: @IAbstract, Normally I would agree except some problems are so contrived that trying to work it out for yourself isn't very easy. I know about this approach as its a translation from functional programming. The OP could have done more research into how other types of languages do this, but that is a lot to ask a beginner IMHO.

Comment: True enough...great answer though!

Answer (score 0):

See the [MSDN Array class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx). This looks like it is c#. Maybe try the `Array.Find<T`> method.

**Update:**
For Java, I'd recommend looking at [Arrays (Java 2 Platform)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29):

binarySearch

> public static int binarySearch(int[]
>   a,
>                                  int key)
>
> Searches the specified array of ints for the specified value using the binary search algorithm. The array  must be sorted (as by the sort method above) prior to making this call. If
>   it is not sorted, the results are
>   undefined. If the array contains
>   multiple elements with the specified
>   value, there is no guarantee which one
>   will be found.
>
> ```
> Parameters:
>     a - the array to be searched.
>     key - the value to be searched for. 
> Returns:
>     index of the search key, if it is contained in the list; otherwise,> (-(insertion point) - 1).
> ```
>
> The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the list: the index of the first  element greater than the key, or list.size(), if all elements 
>   in the list are less than the specified key. Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found. See Also:  sort(int[])

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight issue with your problem. If you are going to use recursion then each array element needs to have a subsey of elements otherwise whay do you passed to the recursive method? If this is not the casr and the case is as you stated then solving this problem with recursion isnot appropriate. Also you are missing the value comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If this is homework and they want it recursive, then maybe you should:

1 look for the middle value of the array and check if it matches. If it matches, return true

2 apply the function to the first half of the array. If it returns true, return true

3 apply the function to the second half of the aray. If it returns true, return true

4 return false

No code since it is homework.

---

EDIT: Is the array ordered?

Comment: The method cannot contain any index elements. Wouldn't your suggestion require index elements to get to the middle? I'm lost on how this is going to be recursive when there are no subset elements as @DaTribe says.

Comment: he will have to copy the array into a new one of the correct size. Yes, highly inefficient, but it is homework (resolving this using recursion is very inefficient, too).

Answer (score 0):

I was just doing the question, and checking answers for alternative ways. Maybe this might be useful when you have to match names to String arrays.

```
public class Recursion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array = {"Tom", "Mary"};
        if(isMember(array,"John"))
            System.out.print("Found!");
        else
            System.out.println("Not Found!");

    }

    public static boolean isMember(String[] array, String name)
    {   
        int i = array.length;
        if(array.length == 0)
            return false;
        if(array[i - 1].equals(name))
            return true;
        else
        {
            String[] array2 = new String[array.length - 1];
            for(int b = 0; b< array.length -1; b++)
            {
                array2[b] = array[b];
            }
            return isMember(array2, name);
        }
    }
}
```